# Django rest framework - set default serializer for a class

Tags: python, json, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

In my code, I have a few models with multiple custom properties:

```py
@dataclass
class Value:
    amount: float
    currency: str

class MyModel(models.Model):
    ...
    
    @property
    def v1(self) -> Value:
        ...
    
    @property
    def v2(self) -> Value:
        ...
    
    @property
    def v3(self) -> Value:
        ...
```

An I have the following serializer:

```py
class MyModelBaseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = [..., "v1", "v2", "v3"]
```

When serializing any `MyModel` instance, a TypeError raises: `TypeError: Object of type Value is not JSON serializable`.

I know this can be solved by explicitly adding `v1, v2, v3` as fields inside `MyModelBaseSerializer`, but I don't want to do that: I have many models with `Value` properties. I want the default DRF serializer to know how to serialize `Value` instances.
I tried overriding `to_representation`, but that didn't seem to work.
I want something similar to overriding the `JSONEncoder.default(o)` method, but I don't see how to tell DRF which encoder to use.

Answer (score 1):

Add a custom serializer for `Value`. For example (not tested).

```
class ValueSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    amount = serializers.FloatField()
    currency = serializers.CharField()


class MyModelBaseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    v1 = ValueSerializer()
    v2 = ValueSerializer()
    v3 = ValueSerializer()
    ...
```

Or, since `Value` is a `dataclass`, take a look at https://github.com/oxan/djangorestframework-dataclasses.

**EDIT**

A quick and dirty DRY approach can be to override `build_property_field` on the serializer ([see docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#the-field_class-and-field_kwargs-api)).

```
class MyModelBaseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def build_property_field(self, field_name, model_class):
        if field_name in ["v1", "v2", "v3"]:
            return ValueSerializer, {}
        return super().build_property_field(field_name, model_class)
```

Overriding [`serializer_field_mapping`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#serializer_field_mapping) is another option.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. As I wrote, I don't wand to explicitly add all fields (I have multiple models like that). Anyway this seems like a counter-DRY solution (though thats what I did for now).